# JAX-RS sub resource is not generated in Quarkus OpenAPI schema

Tags: jakarta-ee, openapi, quarkus, microprofile

Not sure if this is another issue of Subresouce in Quarkus. I got the sub resource work in Quarkus with the help from [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820428/jax-rs-subresource-issue-in-quarkus/57822115).

But when I enable OpenAPI support in this project. The CommentResource(a sub resource of `PostResource`) is not generated in the OpenAPI schema.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/openapi
curl http://localhost:8080/openapi
---
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Generated API
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
  /hello/async:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
  /hello/greeting/{name}:
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: name
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
  /posts:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json: {}
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Post'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*': {}
  /posts/{id}:
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json: {}
    put:
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Post'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*': {}
    delete:
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*': {}
components:
  schemas:
    String:
      type: string
    Post:
      type: object
      properties:
        content:
          type: string
        createdAt:
          format: date-time
          type: string
        id:
          type: string
        title:
          type: string
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3918